# Does FLEX10k support SignalTap?

Tags: fpga, jtag, intel-fpga

Can I make an embedded logic analyzer for FLEX (flex10k) devices using SignalTap by JTAG?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See this [Altera help from Quartus II 11.1](http://quartushelp.altera.com/11.1/mergedProjects/hdl/mega/mega_file_sld_signaltap.htm). Since Flex10k is supported by Quartus II you are good.

Comment: But  "FLEX10k  does not have the internal wiring to support signalTap" as well as  in quartus  v7.2 help mentioned that it not support it?